# Why can't the browser render this table HTML properly?

Tags: html, html-table, markup

I'm struggling with TABLE HTML.
I have no idea why this table tag doesn't work properly in browser

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1-1</td>
      <td rowspan="3">2-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1-3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The html above would be rendered like this

[image]

However the view I expected to see is like this

[image]

As I figured out, If I want to see what I want in browser, I should fix rowspans like this

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">1-1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">2-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">1-3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But I'm really wondering what's different and why The browser (Chrome) doesn't render the first one properly and does the second one.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that what this all comes down to is that you are trying to "abuse" the table to do something that is was not designed to do. For example: if you look at your html it has 4 rows (tr) but you expect it to render to only 3 rows. My impression is that the solution you came up with is kind of a hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to W3C there is no way to specify float value like 1.5 for rowspan but some tweaks like below may help.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1-1</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">2-2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">3-1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm confused that the first html I put doesn't have any float value. Can you give me more details please?

Comment: I meant to say your expected output seems to render by specifying 1.5 times spanning the row which you can't actually use to span the rows. So, by spanning with that way renders the output as you expect

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flexbox yet? It is little bit different approach to solve this.

```css
#main {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
   
   align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
   
}

#main div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    
  
}

#right {
 width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
}

#right div {
 width: 50px;
    height: 75px;
   
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    
    
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;" >1-1</div>
  <div style="background-color:grey;">1-2</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">1-3</div>
<div id="right">
  <div id="right" style="background-color:lightblue;">2-1</div>
  <div id="right" style="background-color:lightgreen;">2-2</div>
</div>
</div>
```